# Update a column in a table based on column in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

The tables are up to 50k rows, and it is taking over an hour to run this. I would like to figure out a way to optimize the query so that it runs more quickly.

tbl1 - serviceid, userid

tbl2 - serviceid, userid, type

tbl1.serviceid values are unique

tbl2.serviceid values are not unique, as they come from a couple of different tables

tbl2.type equals either A or B

(tbl2.serviceid, tbl2.userid, tbl2.type) is unique, and could be set as a multi column primary key if needed

Here is the code I am using in my system to do the updates:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl1";
$rs = full_query ( $sql );
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $rs ) ){
    $sql = "UPDATE tbl2 SET type='A' WHERE serviceid='" . $row->id . "' AND userid='" . $row->userid . "'";
    full_query( $sql );
    $sql = "UPDATE tbl2 SET userid='" . $row->userid . "'  WHERE type='A' AND serviceid='" . $row->id . "'";
    full_query($sql);
}
```

Here is what I ended up using:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl2 t2 INNER JOIN tbl1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.serviceid AND t2.userid = t1.userid SET t2.type = 'A'";
full_query( $sql );
$sql = "UPDATE tbl2 t2 INNER JOIN tbl1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.serviceid AND t2.type='A ' SET t2.userid = t1.userid";
full_query( $sql );
```

Comment: question should not be like: here are the requirements, write the code for me. Please try and post a question if you are stuck on something.

Comment: sure..please post the query you have so far, so people can help

Comment: 1) The SELECT is meaningless, and just wastes time. 2) Your SQL isn't valid, so it can't be what you're really trying. 3) Neither of your UPDATE statements actually does much, so it can't take too long. 4) We can't answer any SQL question that doesn't contain table definitions and the relation between them, and it's even more helpful if you include some sample data from each table and the results you're trying to get from that data afterward. (It also helps if you format your code or SQL properly. Select it and hit Ctrl+K, or indent each line by four spaces.)

Comment: Sorry, never asked a question here before, just used the search to find answers. I updated the question and the code to make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you can solve this with 2 SQL statements. Basically this is doing the same thing.

When you are doing SQL development try to keep in mind that you are using **Set-based theory**, and you should try to avoid loop as much as possible (**Procedural-based programming**).

See this for more detail:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34142/Understanding-Set-based-and-Procedural-approaches

```
-- Update all type to A if [serviceid] and [userid] matches
UPDATE t2 SET t2.type = 'A'
FROM tbl2 t2
    INNER JOIN tbl1 t1
        ON t1.id = serviceid
        AND t2.userid = tbl1.userid;

-- Update all user if [serviceid] and [type] = A matches
UPDATE t2 SET t2.userid = tbl1.userid
FROM tbl2 t2
     INNER JOIN tbl1 t1
        ON t1.id = serviceid
WHERE t2.type = 'A'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I noticed that you use t1, t2, tbl1 and tbl2, but i do not understand what t1 and t2 are doing.

Comment: `t1` and `t2` are SQL Aliases, it is just a name temporarily defined and used within the statement. [detail](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: That was my suspicion, but wanted to make sure. I will test this out. thank.